# How to fetch AWS resource arn using Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have two Jenkins pipeline ; one called log monitoring and another as alert trigger. Both of these pipelines get triggered on any changes to the terraform scripts in Bitbucket.

The pipeline works fine, and the AWS resources are getting created successfully.

The problem that we are facing here is :
The log monitoring pipeline creates an AWS resource, whose ARN we want to fetch from the AWS console and use in  the alert trigger pipeline.

Any thoughts how we can achieve this as we want to automate all the pipeline instead of manually fetching the ARN and triggering the downstream pipeline.

Comment: I attach tags for the resources and then I retrieve ARNs using AWS CLI in shell scripts.

Comment: Thanks @Elzo Valugi . We are tagging the resources created through the log monitoring pipeline. Could you please help me understand , how we can get it's ARN and use in the terraform.tfvars file for alert trigger pipeline ( this file resides in the Bitbucket). Thank you once again !

Comment: Then is a matter of executing a shell script inside your pipeline that will fetch the ARNs that you need.

Comment: Sure, let me give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @Elzo Valugi. As suggested , I am able to fetch the ARN using AWS cli in my shell script inside my first pipeline . I am trying ways to pass this ARN value to my second pipeline.

Comment: I will transform my comment into a response then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach tags to your existing resources and use those to retrieve their respective ARNs using AWS CLI in shell scripts. From that output you can further use that ARN value inside your pipeline in a dynamic manner.

Comment: Thanks @Elzo Valugi. I am able to fetch the ARN using the aws cli. sh 'aws es describe-elasticsearch-domains --domain-name log_monitoring_es_domain'. Once  I get the domain , I am able to fetch the ARN using grep and awk. Now, I have file containing the variable es_host="". I am trying to pass this domain name into this parameter. The below sed command works fine in a linux terminal. However , it does not work in a Jenkins pipeline. Command : sh 'sed -i "s/es_host=\"\"/es_host=\"$my_es_host\"/g" terraform.tfvars ; here my_es_host contains the ARN fetched using AWS cli. Any pointers , TIA.

Comment: check if the value is written correctly in the terraform.tfvars. Do you get any error?

Comment: Thanks @Elzo Valugi for looking into it. I do not get any error, the pipeline just runs fine but the values in terraform.tfvars still remains as es_host="".

Comment: It looks like the write to the tfvars file is not successful